# 3 Where clauses one no entry gives me NULL

Tags: mysql, null, mariadb

I have three tables, payout, earnings, user. I try to get first the userid which I use to get earnings and payouts information about the user. With this I also count together with DISTINCT and substract it to get the CURRENT earnings. The problem is if any of the table has no entry example the payouts table so I get NULL instead of number. How can I solve this. I tried IFNULL but did not work

This is how I do

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT user_earnings.amount) -  
       SUM(DISTINCT user_payouts.payout_amount) as total_earnings  
FROM user, user_earnings, user_payouts 
WHERE user.id = 103 
  and user_earnings.user_id = user.id 
  and user_payouts.user_id = user.id
```

EDIT: I made the current tables
user_earnings  ( the problem is just only with the user_id 103

```
id  user_id  amount
1   102       250
2   102      1000
3   101      5000
4   102       352
18  102       375
19  102       442
20  103       338 <-----
```

user_payouts

```
id  user_id payout_amount   
1   102      500    
2   102      100    
3   101     1000
```

user

```
id  payout_address
102 ***
103 ***
```

As you see payouts have has no entry about user_id 103 because he never did a payout. Thats why I get null (I think)

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out. Join was not easy for me since I do not much mysql (just basic stuffs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, 
     (SUM(DISTINCT ue.amount) - 
       COALESCE(SUM(DISTINCT up.payout_amount),0)) as total_earnings
FROM 
  user u
  left outer join user_earnings ue on u.id = ue.user_id
  left outer join user_payouts up on u.id = up.user_id
WHERE 
  u.id = 103;
```

Sorry, I didn't put enough effort in to the above.  While it will work for a small sample, the above breaks down with a larger set as you are filtering out any instance where a single user got two payouts of the same amount.

I think this is your real solution:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    (ue.earnings - up.payouts) as total_earnings
FROM 
  user u
  inner join 
    (select distinct
        u1.id, 
        SUM(COALESCE(ue.amount,0)) as earnings 
     from 
        user u1 
        left join user_earnings ue on u1.id = ue.user_id group by u1.id) ue on u.id = ue.id
  inner join 
    (select distinct
        u1.id, 
        SUM(COALESCE(up.payout_amount,0)) as payouts 
     from 
        user u1 
        left join user_payouts up on u1.id = up.user_id group by u1.id) up on u.id = up.id
WHERE 
  u.id = 103;
```

Just for fun, here's another option, much shorter:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    ((select COALESCE(SUM(ue.amount),0) from user_earnings ue where ue.user_id = u.id) -
    (select COALESCE(SUM(up.payout_amount),0) from user_payouts up where up.user_id = u.id)) as total_earnings
FROM 
  user u
WHERE 
  u.id = 103;
```

Comment: This worked as excepted. I also add an entry to payouts. The values everything is correct thanks. This is crazy. I need to learn the join things.

Answer (score 1):

**Note1:** 
I would definitely NOT use Distinct in this manner...   If the user in the future has another earned_amount for 338, the second 338 would not get added to the total.

**Note2:**
See my usage of COALESCE instead of IFNULL.

**Note3:**
I updated your join syntax.  Please confirm I kept your join as desired.

**EDIT:**   Updated answer and fiddle to account for duplicate earned_amounts per user as well as duplicate payout_amounts per user

View Fiddle to notice duplicates of both entered for user 103  (400 + 400 - 100 - 100))

CLICK [Here for SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7ff66/1)

```
SELECT (
COALESCE(ue.earned_amount,0) - COALESCE(up.payout_amount,0)
) AS total_earnings
FROM user u 
JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(earned_amount) AS earned_amount 
       FROM Earned
       GROUP BY user_id) ue
    ON ue.user_id = u.id
JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(payout_amount) AS payout_amount
        FROM Payouts
        GROUP BY user_id) up 
    ON up.user_id = u.id

WHERE u.id = 103
```

**Performance Note:**

If your Earned or Payout tables are expected to be large a few ideas for performance improvement will be.

1. limit the size of the returned result sets of the nested queries by adding a Where clause to each so they only return results for user_id 103.
2. Add indexes to both Earned and Payout for the column user_id.
3. OR first create these joins to a temp table with indexes, then join the temp table to this query

Comment: I just tried it. I don't get 0 or null but I get total_earnings = -586 which is wrong. I have one entry in the earnings. Its amount and has value of 338 for the user 103.

Comment: well its not zero, so its a start. :)   Let me look further into this.

Comment: you say you have 1 entry for userID 103 in the ue.Amount for 338.    What do you have for userID 103 in the up.payout_ammount??  it doesn't total 1023 by chance does it?

Comment: I just edit my main thread. There you can check it. payout_amount is empty for userid 103 because he never did a payout (everything is just an example and not real things :P)

Comment: OK, building answer now

Comment: Is it possible you have more then one entry in ue for user 103?  or worse, more then one user 103?

Comment: No. As you see the table I have just one. I also took a solution which gives me the correct number of 338.

Comment: After I corrected my typeo from a "-" to "=" this does give 338 as expected.  It just took me a second to catch it.

Comment: DarbyM is completely correct in her note about why not to use distinct.

Comment: His... HIS note.  Don't blame me, I didn't pick the name. lol

Comment: I don't want to make you angry but I get the 338 but if I make some changes it is not correct. For example I added payout entry 100 and again 100. So total is 200. And earnings are 200 and 300 total 500. So I get 600 intstead of 300 because 500 - 200 = 300 not 600 lol. The solution top (2nd) works perfectly

Comment: Sorry, I had a friend in high school with that name, so I had an internal bias.  My apologies.

Comment: No problem at all MaZy.  I see where my solution might have a hole in it still  (i'm refining the answer still).. I just know from experience the second option chosen with nested query+Joins as written out will suffer from exponential performance degradation.  As early as 20K rows you could be seeing 10second plus queries.

Comment: Darby, I hope you do post your answer when you get it, this one has me a little frustrated as I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 problems -- `DISTINCT`, `JOIN` followed by `GROUP BY`, and failure to deal with `NULL`.

```
SELECT  u.id,
        (
            SELECT ( IFNULL(SUM(amount), 0)
                FROM user_earnings WHERE user_id = u.id ) -
            SELECT ( IFNULL(SUM(payout_amount), 0 )
                FROM user_payouts  WHERE user_id = u.id )
        ) as total_earnings
    FROM  user u
    WHERE  u.id = 103;
```

should solve all of them.

- `DISTINCT` was already discussed -- there could be duplicate value for a given user.
- `JOIN` followed by `GROUP BY` -- I call this "inflate-deflate syndrone".  The `JOIN` happens first, thereby inflating the number of rows, then the `GROUP BY` tries to compensate for it.  Usually this is a performance problem; in your case it mangles the data, too.
- `NULL` was discussed, but I thing this formulation is 'correct'.

This is a 'rare' case where subqueries is better than `LEFT JOIN`.  It avoids the over-calculation of `SUM`.  ghenghy's first solution is probably just as good for a *single* `u.id`; mine should work for multiple ids.